# How to set Radio button selected value in Edit form

Tags: angular, typescript, radio-button, angular6

I am creating edit form using ReactiveFormModule. I want to show data in editform like in textbox, dropdown, radiobox and checkbox. I can set value of textbox and dropdown successfully using `setValue` method. but I can't set value of Radio group using same.

**Typescript**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, FormControlName } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, EMPTY, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.css'],
})
export class AddComponent implements OnInit {
  stateList : any;
  cityList: any;
  genderList: any;
  hobbyList: any;
  name: FormControl;
  age: FormControl;
  state : FormControl;
  city: FormControl;
  myform: FormGroup;
  gender: FormControl;
  hobby: FormControl;
  file: FormControl;
  email: FormControl;
  confirmEmail: FormControl;

  submitted = false;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.name = new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.pattern("")]);
    this.age = new FormControl("27", [checkageValidator]);
    this.state = new FormControl("");
    this.city = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
    this.gender = new FormControl("");
    this.hobby = new FormControl("");
    this.file = new FormControl("");
    this.email = new FormControl("");
    this.confirmEmail = new FormControl("", [compareEmail]);

    this.myform = new FormGroup({
      name: this.name,
      age: this.age,
      state : this.state,
      city: this.city,
      gender: this.gender,
      hobby: this.hobby,
      file: this.file,
      email: this.email,
      Cemail: this.confirmEmail
    });

    this.stateList = [{value : 1, text: "Gujarat"}, {value : 2, text : "Maharastra"}];
    this.cityList = [{ value: 1, text: "Ahmedabad", stateid: 1 }, { value: 2, text: "Rajkot", stateid: 1 }, { value: 3, text: "Gandhinagar", stateid: 2 }];
    this.genderList = [{ value: 1, text: "Male", selected: "checked" }, { value: 2, text: "Female", selected: "" }];
    this.hobbyList = [{ value: 1, text: "Games", checked:false }, { value: 2, text: "Tracking", checked:false }, { value: 3, text: "Swimming", checked:false }];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myform.controls["name"].setValue("Hardik");
    this.myform.controls["state"].setValue("1");
    this.genderList.find(i=>i.value == 2).selected == "checked";
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="myform" (ngSubmit)="SubmitData(myform)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                Name:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" id="txtName" formControlName="name" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'error' : myform.controls.name.errors && submitted}">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && myform.controls.name.errors">
                    <span class="alert-danger form-control" *ngIf="myform.controls.name.errors?.required">Name is required field</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                Email:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" id="txtEmail" formControlName="email" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'error' : myform.controls.email.errors && submitted}">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && myform.controls.email.errors">
                    <span class="alert-danger form-control" *ngIf="myform.controls.email.errors?.required">Email is required field</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                CEmail:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" id="txtCEmail" formControlName="Cemail" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'error' : myform.controls.Cemail.errors && submitted}">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && myform.controls.Cemail.errors">
                    <span class="alert-danger form-control" *ngIf="myform.controls.Cemail.errors?.emailMatch">Email not match</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                Age:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" id="txtAge" formControlName="age" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'error' : myform.controls.name.errors && submitted}">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && myform.controls.age.errors">
                    <span class="alert-danger form-control" *ngIf="myform.controls.age.errors?.required">Age is required field</span>
                    <span class="alert-danger form-control" *ngIf="myform.controls.age.errors?.validAge">Age must greater than 18</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                State:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="state" (change)="getCities($event.target.value)">
                    <option value="">Select State</option>        
                    <option *ngFor="let s of stateList" value="{{s.value}}">{{s.text}}</option>
                </select>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && myform.controls.state.errors">
                    <span class="alert-danger form-control" *ngIf="myform.controls.state.errors?.required">State is Required</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                City:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="city">
                    <option value="">Select City</option>
                    <option *ngFor="let c of cityList" value="{{c.value}}">{{c.text}}</option>
                </select>
                <div *ngIf="submitted && myform.controls.city.errors">
                    <span class="alert-danger form-control" *ngIf="myform.controls.city.errors?.required">City is Required</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                Radio:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <label class="radio-inline" *ngFor="let g of genderList">
                    <input type="radio" [value]="g.value" name="gender" formControlName="gender" [checked]="g.selected">{{g.text}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                CheckBox:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <label class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let g of hobbyList">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="{{g.value}}" name="hobbie" formControlName="hobby" [(ngModel)]="g.checked">{{g.text}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                File:
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <img *ngIf="fileURL != null" [src]="fileURL" style="width: 250px; height: 250;">
                <input type="file" name="file" formControlName="file" accept="image/*" (change)="uploadImage($event.target.files)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, setValue is not working for my RadioButton. so I am setting my JsonData selected property accordingly which is actually wrong as per best practice. isn't it?

What could be the best approach for it?

Comment: Handling of your checked state is custom, you may have to handle the state in a custom way as well, but if you need a prettier code you can create an attribute directive for your box

Answer (score 8):

For the "checked" attribute of radio input, you can check whether current value of the form is equal to the value of radio input.

```
<label class="radio-inline" *ngFor="let g of genderList">
  <input type="radio" [value]="g.value" name="gender" formControlName="gender" 
         [checked]="myform.get('gender').value == g.value">
  {{g.text}}
</label>
```

And then in the component, you can assign required value to the form.

```
this.myform.controls["gender"].setValue(2);
```

Here is the [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwpnv1).